# Ошибка CS0236 при попытке объявить переменную

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio

В классе создал `array`, состоящий из объектов `GameObject`. Затем при попытке создания переменной `blocksAmount` она подсвечивается красным и выдает ошибку:

```
CS0236 : A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property 'Ball.initialBlocksAmount'
```

Ниже код.

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] GameObject[] initialBlocksAmount = UnityEngine.GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("block");
    
    int blocksAmount = initialBlocksAmount.Length;
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять ошибку.

Comment: Для инициализации объекта [есть события](https://habr.com/ru/post/147315/) `Start` и `Awake`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Количество можно получить только внутри какого-либо метода, например

```
int blocksAmount;

public void Start() {
    blocksAmount = initialBlocksAmount.Length;        
}
```

До компиляции, до запуска игры, до создания объекта, компилятор ничего не знает об `initialBlocksAmount` и не может просчитать никакие длины. Потому что это просто класс, черновик, набросок